# App Sandbox blocks creation of .sqlite-shm, .sqlite-wal files (swift)

Tags: swift, macos, sqlite, target

About my problem: I used https://theswiftdev.com/2017/10/27/how-to-launch-a-macos-app-at-login/ for launch my mac-OS app at login it work good. After time I found some problem in my application. My app generated  sqlite files like  sqlite-shm, .sqlite-wal but after added changеs  as "launch" it does't work  now.
problems in with **"App Sendbox"** it included as "on" if I change to "off" my files will be create but "launch" will not be work

How to make these two features work?
Can you help my with my problem?

Comment: Nobody knew about this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok! i found answer to my question my self)
If it well be halpfully to another peoples i will by happy.
Ok! let's start)
First we are need delete all code as this is linc (of course if you did as in this linc) and then disable the sandbox (cause it blocks kreating sql.lite files)
and second we are need add to info.plist this:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

and thats all)